# Add previous value on array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to figure out how to make an array add the value of the previous array, so far, looking at the PHP manual I got how to add a single value for each position of the array, but I don't understand how can I add the previous value to the actual value.
That's what i got checking the manual:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <?php
           foreach (array(422, 322, -52323, 7452) as &$val) {
            $val = $val + 2;
            
                echo "$val<br>";

           }
        ?>
    </body>
```

I know that I have to change the "**+ 2**" with "**add previous value**" but don't know how I can tell it to do that, tried to add "*$val[0]*" or "*$val[$i]*" but not doing what I think it does.

Thank you!

Comment: Try storing the array and using `as $key => &$val` instead of just `as &$val`, then you can use the `$key` variable, such as `$array[$key - 1]`.

Answer (score 5):

You've complicated matters by putting the array directly into `foreach`. To get the previous value, you need to have access to the array itself.

Once you have that, you can get the index of the current value with `foreach`, which you can use to determine the index of the previous value:

```
$array = array(422, 322, -52323, 7452);
foreach ($array as $index => &$val) {
    // the first index is 0, in that case there is no previous value
    // (trying to access $array[$index - 1] ($array[-1]) will fail then)
    if ($index > 0) {
        $val = $val + $array[$index - 1];
    }

    echo "$val<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly iterating over an array, and in that case you don't need the reference to `&$val`, you can just use `$val`

If you don't want to store the array in a variable, you could also "remember" the previous value of the iteration (which will also work in case the keys are not numerical [for example](https://3v4l.org/iCMAT))

```
$previous = null;
foreach (array(422, 322, -52323, 7452) as $val) {
    if ($previous) {
        $previous += $val;
    } else {
        $previous = $val;
    }
    echo $previous . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
422
744
-51579
-44127
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/NcheI).